Scrolling by up/down arrows doesn't work for Safari
I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.4.1. Both with the built-in and an external keyboard scrolling by the up/down arrow keys does not work for Safari. It does work for other apps like Mail, Preview etc where the content is for reading (not editing). Any idea why this is the case? If it's a bug, is there any workaround?
I tried to search google, but didn't get any satisfactory answers. Thanks!

I also have this problem. I have to restart Safari to fix it, but it quickly breaks again.

I recently had this issue, as well. It also would scroll up when I press down, but only occasionally. During this error, the spacebar would also not scroll. I opened the screen keyboard to test if the on-screen arrow keys would scroll a currently non-arrow-key-scrolling page: they did. But the interesting thing is the keyboard arrows started working again. Not sure how long this will last, but it appears that at least opening the screen keyboard might fix the issue, but you may also have to click on arrow keys to actually fix it.. hopefully for good.

Thank you for your answer; it was really helpful. Yes the method works and as you suspected, it stops working after sometime until I open the screen keyboard once again. I did not see it stop working in a single session though. Looks like it happens after the computer has gone through a few sleep cycles.

I changed the mouse keys scroll wheel settings on my keyboard. Now I use that in all my browsers. I still need to tweak things a bit, such as making it take longer to get to full speed, but I think I might like this better than the arrow keys. Sometimes when Apple breaks things my work around ends up better than the original.

I use the old fashioned keyboard-mouse system. Mouse scrolling always worked. The problem is many a times I don't want to switch to mouse just for scrolling. It's just not good for my arm, given the length of time I'm engaging. In that case I do need the scrolling to be done just from the keyboard (KB).
Given your observation, I created a KB binding to move the focus to the menu bar where the KB icon appears and then launch Show Keyboard Viewer and then hide it back to activate the key-scrolling if it got deactivated automatically - all done without switching to the mouse.
